# Adding overflow to dropdown hide the submenu

Tags: html, css

Hello I have a long dropdown-menu and the demanded task is adding scrollbar to it knowing that have dropdown-submenu inside, when adding  `overflow-y:auto, height:500px` it hide the submenus while scroll.

```html
 <li class="dropdown notforacheteur">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle header-drop-down" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true"
             aria-expanded="false" style="    background-color: unset !important;min-width: 200px;">Administration <span
                      class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu primaryScrollMenu" style=" overflow-y:auto; height:500px;   margin-top: 15px;">
    
              <li class="dropdown-submenu left">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown link </a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="right: 100%;">
                      <li><a href="#" target="_blank">sublinks</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Sublinks</a></li>
                  </ul>
              </li>
          </ul>
      </li>
```

Comment: Would help a little to see your CSS or know which framework you're using if that's the case

Comment: I use php and try to add  overflow-y:auto, height:500px through the ul for adding scrollbar

Comment: @Badr could you please add it into your question instead of telling us?

Comment: @GucciBananaKing99 yes already add it on ul.dropdown-menu thanks